# Best approach for implementing angular in existing gwt applications new menu

Tags: angular, gwt

Its a legacy GWT application. There is a requirement to have a new menu. This new main wanted to implement using angular6+.
What will be the possibilities for this.

After a bit of searching I had found out one possible solution is

1. iFrame

create a new angular project. Add a router. Use this route path in GWT application in iframe. Problem with approach is we don't want to create a separate project.

2)Angular Element

I don't have much knowledge about this. Can I create a component and use that component in a gwt application ?

Is there any other approach for adding angular in existing gwt application ?

Comment: I'm not sure how exactly GWT engine works, but that's pretty much the classic example of using Angular Element. Don't be afraid to use it, you should just link the package as you do with any scripts and add components like any other web component.

Comment: There is no index.html here. There are jsp files. I can bootstrap the application there?

Comment: JSP eventually render into HTML, as long as you have the rights tags like <ang-universal><anguniversal/> it should work ( almost ) exactly as web component. and inject the script with 'ScriptInjector'

Comment: However for maintenance and ease of readability and if you're familiar with iFrames, merge both solutions, use Angular element inside of your iFrame so all Angular stuff will go in the same place. You don't have to create a whole new application, you can simply create another  entry point for your application. ( It's as easy as 2 lines of code, and a new component you register ).

Comment: How can i give separate entry in a jsp application  only for the angular menu.

Comment: In your Angular app module you Override ngDoBoottstrap and bootstrap the compounent you want to.
I think this is for angular 6, if you wantto have many elements you can use with resolveComponentFactory.
Anyway it should look somewhat like:
`export class AppBrowserModule implements DoBootstrap {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {

   const menuElement = createCustomElement(menuComponent, {
            injector: injector
        });
        customElements.define("angular-menu", menuElement);
}
    ngDoBootstrap(app: ApplicationRef) {
            app.bootstrap(AppComponent);

}`